# Virtual Black Box Obfuscator

Tags: io, obfuscation

For which class of circuits does the Virtual black box(VBB) obfuscator exists? If so Why? What are the attempts/further developments made in this topic?

Answer (score 5):

While the question was different, you can extract the answer from my answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67696/obfuscating-functions-that-are-mostly-zero). Summing up:

- Under LWE, we have (distributional) VBB obfuscation for conjunctions
- Under multilinear maps (the flavor of which can possibly be constructed from iO, which itself now exists under relatively standard assumptions), we have VBB for evasive low-degree polynomials modulo a prime
- Under entropic DDH, we have (distributional) VBB for pattern matching and hyperplane membership
- Under exponentially strong OWFs (or OWP), we have VBB for point functions

On the other hand, via [the classical result of Barak, Goldreich, Impagliazzo, Rudich, Sahai, Vadhan, and Yang](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2001/21390001.pdf?_gclid=5af080e8752640.39953774-5af080e87526b3.81560462&_utm_source=xakep&_utm_campaign=mention57305&_utm_medium=inline&_utm_content=lnk264415011850), whenever the class of functions contains a PRF, you cannot have VBB obfuscation for it.